# How do I enable Zen Coding in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, emmet

I'm a complete emacs newbie.

I've added the zencoding-mode.el to my .emacs.d dir. I've added it to the init.el like this:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "C:/Documents and Settings/jwharton/Application Data/.emacs.d/zencoding/")
(require 'zencoding-mode)
(add-hook 'sgml-mode-hook 'zencoding-mode)
```

When I enable it in the buffer (M-x zencoding-mode) and attempt to use it, it does highlight the term (in my case html:5 - C-RET) but then gives me an error:

```
zencoding-preview-post: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
```

This gives me the same error on OS X. My load-path is different there obviously...

Google returns nothing so I'm scratching my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem. In which way do you "attempt to use it"? Are you aware that C-RET is not something you're expected to type literally into the buffer, but instead means you should press the keys <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>return</kbd> at the same time?

Also, there should be no need to invoke `M-x zencoding-mode` manually. The line

```
(add-hook 'sgml-mode-hook 'zencoding-mode)
```

is meant to activate zencoding-mode automatically in HTML buffers.

Comment: It looks like I was trying to make it work in a scratch buffer.... as soon as I opened a file with an HTML extension, it worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's intended to be used like that, get rid of the hook and set up a shortcut like:

```
(define-key my-keys-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-1") 'zencoding-expand-line)
```

Comment: No, you're right. I can manually enable it in a scratch buffer by using M-x zencoding-mode.

Answer (score 0):

Open zencoding-mode.el and locate zencoding-default-filter function. It tries to guess filter based on the current filename and fails if you run it in scratch buffer.

Replace (buffer-file-name) expression with (or (buffer-file-name) "") and it should work fine again.